# HTML5 File Reader API: the event 'onload' does not fire

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new with AngularJS, HTML5 and JavaScript. I'm doing a service in angularjs that reads text files. I'm using the HTML5 File Reader API. The problem is that the event 'onload'(or other) does not fire. This is the service:

```
angular.module('uploadFiles').factory('readFileAsTextService', function () {
    return {
        readFile: function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                if ((file !== undefined) && (file !== null)) {   
                    reader.onload = function (event) {
                        return event.target.result;
                    };
                    reader.readAsText(file);
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

And here the controller:

```
angular.module('uploadFiles').controller('UploadFileController', ['$scope', 'validFileExtensions', 'readRouteAsTextService',
    function FileUploadCtrl($scope, validFileExtensions, readFileAsTextService) {

        $scope.setFiles = function (element) {
            $scope.$apply(function ($scope) {

                $scope.files = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
                    if validFileExtensions.validate(element.files[i].name,filesExtensions)) {
                        $scope.files.push(element.files[i]);
                        filesText[i] = readFileAsTextService.readFile(element.files[i]);
                    }
                }

            });
        };
}]);
```

Comment: Add a example where you are using this service. Show the code

Comment: Added a part of controller. Thanks!

Comment: why are you using $scope.$apply inside $scope.setFiles? Where are you using it?

Comment: I think I need if I want to display the list of files in my partial html (update watchers) after changes. The controller is longer, I've only written a part for simplicity.

Comment: You have syntax error on if statment,  can it be causing further page processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to show a code that must works:

```
angular.module('uploadFiles').factory('readFileAsTextService', ["$q", function ($q) {
    return {
        readFile: function (file) {
            var deferread = $q.defer();
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                if ((file !== undefined) && (file !== null)) {
                    reader.onload = function (event) {
                        deferred.resolve(event.target.result);
                    };
                    reader.readAsText(file);
                }else{
                    deferred.resolve("You need to pass a file.");
                }
            }else{
                deferred.resolve("Your browser don't support File api.");
            }

            return deferread.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

and in your controller:

```
angular.module('uploadFiles').controller('UploadFileController', ['$scope', 'validFileExtensions', 'readRouteAsTextService',
    function FileUploadCtrl($scope, validFileExtensions, readFileAsTextService) {

        $scope.setFiles = function (element) {

            $scope.files = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
                if(validFileExtensions.validate(element.files[i].name,filesExtensions)) {
                    $scope.files.push(element.files[i]);
                    (function(i){
                        readFileAsTextService.readFile(element.files[i]).then(function(text){
                            filesText[i] = text;
                        })
                    })(i);
                }
            }

        };
}]);
```

Tell me if it works.